# socket programming - can we send multiple sendto() from the same socket using a for loop

Tags: python, sockets, udp

```
lines = f.readlines()
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for line in lines:
    client.sendto(line.encode(), (serverName,serverport))
    res,address = client.recvfrom(1024)
    res = res.decode()
```

The code does not send requests on the second iteration of the for loop. I am confused by how to approach this.

Comment: yes of coarse you can ... your client isnt returning anything so you are hanging on the recvfrom ... use a timeout or have your client respond or remove the recvfrom all together if you are not actually using res

Comment: The client receives the first response, but since it failed to send the second request it doesn't receive the second response

Comment: the client **must** respond or currently it will block on the line that has the recvfrom forever ... or until the client replies ... **you can** remove that line  ... **or** set a timeout ... **or** respond from the client every time you recv on the client

Comment: The client always responds as it receives. Our client always just prints out the data and sends it back with a status code in front of it. We are able to read this status code on the first loop but it stops working in the second loop. Also, I can ensure the line works since it is able to access that before it stops working.

Comment: which line hangs? ... put prints between them if you are unsure ... as i mention in the answer UDP is inherently lossy so its possible(but unlikely) the response is getting lost ... more likely is that it also only gets it if its ACTIVELY listening when the other end sends it ... so add a small delay before your reply maybe? (I added this suggestion to my answer ... but i assure you we use this exact pattern at my place of work with UDP and it just works)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out based on your responses! Have a great day/night

Answer (score 0):

## server.py

```
lines = "hello\nworld\nmulti\nline".splitlines()
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for line in lines:
    client.sendto(line.encode(), (serverName,serverport))
    # recvfrom will block **until** it gets a reply
    res,address = client.recvfrom(1024)
    res = res.decode()
```

## client.py

```
...
while True:
    data,address = server.recvfrom(1024)
    print(f"RECV: {data!r}")
    # allow a small delay to make sure the other end is actively waiting on a response when you send
    time.sleep(0.1)
    server.sendto(b"OK\r\n",address)
    print("Replied so server can go on")
```

since udp is inherently lossy (although generally not) you might still want to put a timeout on the client in the **server.py** script ... or remove the expectation of a response by simply removing the `res,addres = client.recvfrom(...)` line